# Why can't I deploy to GAE using the gcloud command in go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to deploy an application written in go to GAE. When I call `gcloud app deploy` it says this:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 64850a38-3b7b-4223-97bc-27643b8ab1d5 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: go build: cannot use -o with multiple packages
.
Check the build log for errors: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/64850a38-3b7b-4223-97bc-27643b8ab1d5?project=609165667740
```

I have looked everywhere but I can't find information related to this error in this context.

Comment: In my experience, this type of error occur depending on the folder structure of your project. But I'd need more information in order to help you out. 1. Can you share the folder structure of your project? 2. The error log of your appengine project should give you further information about the error. 3. Are you deploying the project to GAE flexible or standard environment? 4. This error is related to multiple binaries (i.e. multiple files with package main and func main() {}). Make sure you have only one file related to main package and main function. if that's the case.

Comment: the project is on the GOPATH, and I onlye have 3 go files on the folder, plus some templates under a templates folder. I am deploying to GAE standard. The error log only says error. The log is here: https://pastebin.com/jkdhYrud

Comment: Try placing your project files under a subfolder along with your .yaml file instead of straight into your $GOPATH. The error is probably occurring because gcloud is trying to compile and deploy all the other dependency packages you have in your project. Then run the gcloud deploy command on this subfolder specifically. Your log gives you a clue about the issue. "Step #1 - "builder": 2019/04/05 07:37:07 Your app is not on your GOPATH, this build may fail."

Comment: It still fails. Under the GOPATH i created a folder called myapp, and in that folder I placed all the required files but it still fails

Comment: here is my structure https://pastebin.com/AWqtLne9

Comment: Where's your $GOPATH pointing to?

Comment: /home/eduardo/code/go

Comment: Show us your go env ouput.

Comment: I solved it based in the comments. It turns I was using Ubuntu and my GOPATH is actually a symbolic link to a folder in my windows partition, but gcloud was using the full path. I set the GOPATH to the full path (/mnt/hdd/.../Documents/code/go) and it worked